# Android emulator timeout error at titanium

Tags: android, macos, titanium

I am working on mac and using titanium studio.

Every time I run android emulator I get the following error

> [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process
>   exit value was 1
>   [ERROR] :  Emulator failed to start in a timely
>   manner The current timeout is set to 120000 ms You can increase this
>   timeout by running: titanium config android.emulatorStartTimeout

Can anyone help?

Comment: have you tried increasing the timeout (by running  titanium config android.emulatorStartTimeout)?

Comment: Please, please think about how you could increase the amount of relevant information in your subject line.

Comment: How to increase time out.can u write the syntax?

Comment: New to this technology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up a terminal window an use the following command:

```
titanium config android.emulatorStartTimeout 0
```

You could also let the emulator start up and unlock the screen, when it is ready launch the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting android device and click run as android device. Running app in device takes less time than in emulator.